# QGIS Overlapping OSM Isochrones

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, union, isochrone

[image]

These are 3 Isochrones created with the OSM-Tool. They are marking catchment areas for footwalking. 
Since im pretty new to QGIS I have no idea how to unite the isochrones into 1 Isochrone. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

on the top menu use vector > geoprocessing tools > dissolve. On the tool's dialogue box, uncheck the "dissolve all" check box and add the attribute that defines your isochrones in the "Unique ID fields" "selected" box. You can save the output to a shapefile or keep it as a temporary layer in the last box.

Take a look [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1mM368efVAhVMvRoKHUP8Ar0QtwIIJjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOpPxkwBqOzs&usg=AFQjCNHTpvGGDKWRFtZksc3NtVEmWTvWag) for a video tutorial on the dissolve tool